# Hadoop on mac, Resource Manager, is not starting

Tags: macos, hadoop

```
CKui-MacBook-Pro:~ CK$ /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.2.1/sbin/start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
Starting datanodes
Starting secondary namenodes [CKui-MacBook-Pro.local]
2019-12-15 18:53:28,670 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
CKui-MacBook-Pro:~ CK$ /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.2.1/sbin/start-yarn.sh
Starting resourcemanager
Starting nodemanagers
CKui-MacBook-Pro:~ CK$ jps
32689 Jps
32563 NodeManager
32234 SecondaryNameNode
31983 NameNode
```

I dont know why but resource manager is not starting eventually, and therefore, the localhost:8088 is not found. Everything else is fine like localhost:9870 and 9868

How do i fix this problem? I am using hadoop 3.2.1 on mac homebrew

thanks

Comment: Go to the logs folder in Homebrew Hadoop folder and see why resource manager fails

Answer (score 0):

check whether 
`fs.defaultFS` in /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.2.1/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml

```xml
<property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
```

and `yarn.resourcemanager.address` in /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.2.1/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml

```xml
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
  <value>localhost:9001</value>
</property>
```

using the same port